# Percentages for geom_text in stacked barplot with counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I want to have a stacked barplot with percentages in it based on counts.
I have almost reached what I want but every value in the text is 100% instead of the real percentage ...
I think there is one small mistake in my code but I can not find it.

```
ggplot(
  mtcars,
  aes(fill = factor(gear), 
      x = factor(carb))
) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "count", 
           position = "fill", 
           color = "black",
           width = 0.5) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..prop..)), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5), 
            stat = "count") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw stacked bars in ggplot2 that show percentages based on group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231124/how-to-draw-stacked-bars-in-ggplot2-that-show-percentages-based-on-group)

Comment: No because I cannot use `stat = "identity"`. But thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49566235/1842673)

You can use this:

```r
ggplot(
  mtcars,
  aes(fill = factor(gear), 
      x = factor(carb))
) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "count", 
           position = "fill", 
           color = "black",
           width = 0.5) + 

  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..])),
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5),
            stat = "count") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]