# Put percentages by factor on stacked bars in ggplot for each factor (without summarising the data)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

How to put percentages computed for each column (`V1 = T` and `V1 = F`)

I tried the following, but it computes the percentages for the whole.

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), V2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(df) +
  aes(x = V1, fill = V2) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack") +
  stat_count(position = "stack", aes(label = paste0(round(..count../sum(..count..) * 100),"%")), geom = "text", size = 5, vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very similar approach to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59448801/12545041) answer. However, the syntax is updated as dot dot notation (`..count..` etc.) was deprecated in `ggplot 3.4.0` ([November 2022](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/ggplot2-3-4-0/)). You can now use [`after_stat(count)`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html):

```r
ggplot(df) +
  aes(x = V1, fill = V2) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack") +
  geom_text(stat = "count",
        aes(
            label = paste0(
                round(after_stat(count) / tapply(count, x ,sum)[x] * 100),
                "%"
            )
        ),
        size = 5, 
        vjust = 1.15
    )
```

[image]

Comment: You're using `tapply`, which is used to summarise data. So I wil not accept this anwser for the moment